# After using importRange to get Hyperlinked cells, how do you get the value of the URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to help someone solve a problem the other day and I came across an interesting issue I couldn't solve.

Imagine two sheets. One containing HYPERLINKS created by HYPERLINK function in Google Sheets, such as this sheet.
[Source Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hVr-PnmpAj7VaT6xTfwhMAS2zi-JzruDZcjvHzQIpyk/edit?usp=sharing)

Then you have another sheet that uses importRange to import these URL's, like this sheet.
[import Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5Zt-7ByW8A17kKPdcIBs_gzH8RuM4n3Q5aW6mHxyKM/edit?usp=sharing)

The URLs import correctly, with correct link and link text.
But no matter what I tried, in the import sheet, I couldn't extract the link value.

I tried to do this via formulas and via scripting. I'm guessing the URL must be some sort of object but I cannot seem to read or split it. Whatever efforts I've tried have always returned the link text, EG Google, Yahoo and not the URL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to getting the hyperlink value from the cell. getValues, getDisplayValues, even getDataSourceUrl do not return the hyperlink value, only the display value as a string. And because this is from an IMPORTRANGE getFormulas will only return an empty array.

If you want you can put in a feature request at:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list