# importrange doesn´t bring the text with the hiperlink, only brings the text

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets  `importrange` doesn´t bring the text with the hiperlink, only brings the text, any advice? I read a post that explains how to extract the link. But I think its not my case how to resolve. Also I don´t see in the menus how to tell that cell is hiperlink. Any Advice?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After using importRange to get Hyperlinked cells, how do you get the value of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285195/after-using-importrange-to-get-hyperlinked-cells-how-do-you-get-the-value-of-th)

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, google sheets importrange does not support hyperlinks. you will need to extract them in your source sheet and reconstruct them in your data sheet.